# Including pstex_t figures when using htlatex

Tags: graphics, floats, html, htlatex, ps

I am trying to create html file from my  `test.tex` document including a  `.pstex_t` file that include a  `.ps`  figure. Here is my  `test.tex` file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\title{Test}
\author{S.~Oulhoussine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^2+\sqrt{i}}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\input{invariant.pstex_t}
\caption{Ensemble borné.} \label{f:snlbf}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

The `.ps` an `.pstex_t` files are here in the link below
[invariant.ps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17WeC2BlxELyTQ7eETgBwO-CIUFNTzii_) and [invariant.pstex_t](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18MyVMyZmiL6y6h5O9xU4o1na6z6-ojw_)
The  `.pstex_t` is created using Winfig from a winfig figure including math formulaes in Latex.
All is going ok to create  `.dvi`  file.
To convert to  `.html` , I use  `tex4ht`  with `my.cfg` configuration file listed below

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS- 
MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
.MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I used this command line
`htlatex test.tex "my.cfg"`
Here is my `html` file
[test.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bM8HwUDcLqFRp0Nb9T2-oYKG2b3x1cli)

As you can see, the figure does not appear in the `.html` file.
How to include `.pstex_t`using `tex4ht` please ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you edit your question with a clear explanation, please?

Comment: I think we will need some example. TeX4ht can include PS files, but I haven't heard about `pstex_t` before and cannot find a sample file online, so I cannot came with a solution at the moment.

Comment: I updated my Question and added files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `.pstex_t` file looks like this:

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)%
\includegraphics{invariant.ps}%
\end{picture}%
%
%  Created by WinFIG version 4.9 
%  METADATA <version>1.0</version> 
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{3947sp}%
%
\begingroup\makeatletter\ifx\SetFigFont\undefined%
\gdef\SetFigFont#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \reset@font\fontsize{#1}{#2pt}%
  \fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}%
  \selectfont}%
\fi\endgroup%
\begin{picture}(2865,1549)(2382,-1432)
%  METADATA <id>4</id> 
\put(4725,-814){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{{\SetFigFont{12}{14.4}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}$x(t_0)$}%
}}}}
%  METADATA <id>6</id> 
\put(3184,-764){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{{\SetFigFont{12}{14.4}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}$x(t)$}%
}}}}
%  METADATA <id>8</id> 
\put(5018,-56){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{{\SetFigFont{12}{14.4}{\rmdefault}{\mddefault}{\updefault}{\color[rgb]{0,0,0}$\mathcal{M}$}%
}}}}
\end{picture}%
```

It is just regular LaTeX code that includes a PS image and then uses picture mode to draw some math over the image.

TeX4ht provides the `\Picture+{} ... \EndPicture` environment which can be used to convert the enclosed content to picture. We just need to insert it somehow to the document. The best way is to provide a custom command for the `pstex_t` image inclusion, to be used instead of usual `\input`. It can look like this:

```
\newcommand\inputpstex[1]{\input{#1.pstex_t}}
```

The image will be then included using:

```
\inputpstex{invariant}
```

In the `.cfg` file, we will redefine this command to use the `\Picture+` command:

```
\let\originputpstex\inputpstex
\renewcommand\inputpstex[1]{\Picture+{}\originputpstex{#1}\EndPicture}
```

The full example:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537131/2891
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newcommand\inputpstex[1]{\input{#1.pstex_t}}
\title{Test}
\author{S.~Oulhoussine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^2+\sqrt{i}}
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\inputpstex{invariant}
\caption{Ensemble borné.} \label{f:snlbf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,mathjax}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
.MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\let\originputpstex\inputpstex
\renewcommand\inputpstex[1]{\Picture+{}\originputpstex{#1}\EndPicture}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

(I've simplified it a bit, we now have built-in support for MathJax in TeX4ht)

Compile your document using:

```
 make4ht -c my.cfg test.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you undeed micha.h21. It worked nice.

Comment: @SaïdOulhoussine that's great! :)